# GridFSDBFile in spring boot 2.0.1 release

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate spring boot 1.5.7 to its latest version realease 2.0.1. In the old version I used this syntax to recover a file.

```
GridFSDBFile gridFsdbFile = gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(fileId)));
```

Do you know how it would be done in the new version? I need

```
file.setInputStream(gridFsdbFile.getInputStream());
```

ty!

Answer (score 4):

```
GridFSFile gridFsdbFile = gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)));

GridFSDownloadStream gridFSDownloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStream(gridFsdbFile.getObjectId());
GridFsResource gridFsResource = new GridFsResource(gridFsdbFile,gridFSDownloadStream );
```

then

```
file.setInputStream(gridFsResource.getInputStream());
```

You can define gridFSBucket in MongoConfiguration like this

```
@Bean public GridFSBucket getGridFSBuckets() {
MongoDatabase db = mongoDbFactory().getDb();
return GridFSBuckets.create(db);
}
```

Comment: how can save file, I'm trying: 

`ObjectId id = gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, filename, contentType, metaData);
return Mono.just(id.toString()).block();`

Comment: I had an issue using only `gridFsTemplate.getResource(gridFSFile.getFilename());` to load a PDF content, causing a malformed file: startxref not found
This solved my problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Seems that since Spring Boot 2.0.x GridFS operations are mowing towards Resource approach.

Given you have **unique** file names in your GridFS, you can do like this:

```
gridFsTemplate.getResource("my-file-name.txt")
```

Any arbitary ID can be used instead of real file name to ensure its uniqueness when storing the file (e.g. ObjectId).

```
gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, "5a55f1ea29485119f7a671a7")
```

Also there is [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/aab86d23c9eb37ef3d7db05d84327c9fe55b51d0#diff-126374d4123dd395bf65211b641d4a7f) in 2.1.0.M3 with helper method for getting resource by GridFSFile, but under the hood it still uses **file name**.

---

In order to get file content by **pure ID** you can use something like this:

```
GridFSBuckets.create(dbFactory.getDb()).openDownloadStream(gridFsFileId)
```

Answer (score 0):

a temporary solution to leave it the same is to include the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.10.11.RELEASE