# spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb don't include GridFSBucket bin as autoconfigured

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

GridFSBucket is not auto configured in Spring boot parent in 2.1.3.REALEASE, so cant be autowired. But GridFsTemplate is autowire as it is autoconfigured. how to get gridFSBucket from gridFsTemplate. Actually i want to use 'downloadToStream' method to write to a file. If that is possible by GridFSFile then not required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while migrating, trying to load a PDF stored in MongoDB, causing the file to be corrupted (startxref not found)

Following this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732308/590374

Answer (score -1):

```
GridFSFile file = gridFsTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(fileId)));
GridFsResource resource = gridFsTemplate.getResource(file);
return resource.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and include some explanation? Code-only answers are considered as low quality posts